# Pointer Confusion

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I need to access a c-string called name. name is part of a class called Data. There is an array of structs in a separate class, and the structs contain Data objects. I'm bad at pointers, and can't seem to figure out how to access name. Here's some code to clarify. Obviously I have much more to do, but I was hoping to find the solution to this problem before I finished my implementation.

```
bool BST::retrieve(const char *key, Data const *& data) const
{
    int rIndex = 0;
    if (strcmp(items[rIndex]->data.name, key) == 0)

    return false;
}
```

In BST

```
private:
struct Item
{
    Data   data;
    bool isEmpty = true;
}
Item *items;  //initialized in constructor to be size of a capacity argument
```

In Data

```
private:
char * name;
```

The first argument of the strcmp is where I'm having issues. Thanks for any help. Sorry if the question isn't clear enough.

Comment: Going to assume `BST` is friended by `Data`, or that private member `name` isn't going to be accessible from `BST::retrieve` (after you fix the syntax as Daniel points out below).

Comment: @WhozCraig It isn't, which I think has led to the error that Data::name is inaccessible. Unfortunately, I can't change the source file for Data in this assignment. Any other workarounds you might suggest?   

EDIT: Turns out I already wrote an accessor function that I forgot about

Comment: Lovely. The data item isn't accessible directly, but did the fiend that wrote it make it accessible via a "getter" of some kind (look for a `getName()` method or some such). If they didn't they had better have given you a functional comparator that does what your `strcmp` is doing now that *they* wrote and you supply two `Data` pointers/references to. (and honestly that isn't a half-bad idea *regardless*).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, they did include an accessor which I implemented about a week ago and then subsequently forgot about. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `.` operator for your `Item` rather than the `->` operator.

`items` is an array of `Item` objects. When you use the `[]` operator to dereference it, what you get back is a reference, not a pointer.

So try

```
strcmp(items[rIndex].data.name, key)
```

Comment: Thanks, I could have sworn I tried that combination but must not have. A new problem has arisen, however. Now I get an error that says Data::name is inaccessible. Care to shed any light on that?

Answer (score 2):

Data::name is private so will be inaccessible as has already been pointed out.

To fix this you need to add a public accessor method to your Data class

```
class Data
{

  public:
    char const* getName() const
    {
       return name;
    }

   ...
}
```

and then your calling code would look like this

```
if (strcmp(items[rIndex].data.getName(), key) == 0)
```

Comment: Oh yeah, turns out I'm just a little slow as I had already written an accessor function. Thanks for pointing that out!